# <a> encompassing more content than intended

Tags: php, html, href

I put a video and its title into a content block. I tried to wrap the title in an `<a>` tag, but the video and controls are also included in the link so that when I push "play" the link opens. I want only the title to be linked. What's going wrong?

PHP:

```php
echo"<p id='artContent'>
    <a href='".$array1[$e]->video."' target='_new'>".$array1[$e]->titulo; "</a></p> \n ";
echo "\n ";
echo" <video width='95%' height='auto' preload='none' src='".$array1[$e]->video."' poster='img/portfolio/local.png' controls controlsList='nodownload'></video>";
```

CSS:

```css
#artContent {
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  font-weight: 2.8em;
  background-color: #f8f8f8; /*color de los cuadros de video*/
  color: #169ed5; /*color de las letras de los videos*/
  display: table-row;
  width: 33%;  
}
```

Comment: The semicolon after `$array1[$e]->titulo;` [terminates](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) that PHP statement, so the `</a>` is never echoed. Replace the semicolon with a period to complete the concatenation and the string should output as intended.

Comment: Thank's a lot the issue was resolved.

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding!